# Why setVisibility only works setOnClickListener but not in onClick?

Tags: android

I have two buttons for languages and I want to hide them after clicking on one of them. When I add `onClick` event in the XML file and try to hide the buttons, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.english);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.arabic);
        }

    public void on_english(View view) {
        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

When I use `button1.setOnClickListener` it works well:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.english);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.arabic);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Are there any mistakes in my code when I use `onClick` event?

Why does the `setVisibility` only work with `setOnClickListener`?
XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Start.MainActivity"
    android:background="@mipmap/back">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/label1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="English"
        android:id="@+id/english"
        android:onClick="on_english"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="العربية"
        android:id="@+id/arabic"
        android:onClick="on_arabic"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/english"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: java != android

Comment: Show us your xml file too, looks like the mistake is in your xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just do this :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == button1) {
        // if view == english

        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (view == button2) {
        // if view == arabic

        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

just add on your onCreate :

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Additional note : You can use butterknife by jake wharton which is available [at this link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) for view injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use `view.setVisibility()` instead.

Edit: Use `view.getId()` to get the ID of the button (R.id.yourButtonId) and do a `if` statement to set visibility.

Comment: it doesn't work and even if it worked, it will hide one button only

Comment: yes, but I used button1 and button2 inside the method to hide them both but if i used view this will affect button1 only

Comment: Use `view.getId` to get the buttons and do a switch case. Let me update my answer...